# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t[Yn] is not a function in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

My for:each loop fails with this TypeError:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t[Yn] is not a function
at i (aura_prod.js:3)
at n (/flexipageEditor/modules/c/eventWithData.js:4)
at mo (aura_prod.js:3)
at yr (aura_prod.js:3)
at bo (aura_prod.js:3)
at aura_prod.js:3
at To (aura_prod.js:3)
at cr (aura_prod.js:3)
at Array.ir (aura_prod.js:3)
at Bt (aura_prod.js:3)
```

The code looks like this:

```
<template> <lightning-card title="EventWithData" icon-name="standard:logging">
  <div class="slds-m-around_medium"> 
    <template if:true={contacts.data}> 
      <p>Gopal Singh</p> 
        <template for:each={contacts} for:item='con'> 
          <p key={con.id}>{con.Title}</p> 
        </template> 
    </template> 
  </div> 
  </lightning-card> 
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, i had this same issue. Can you share your apex code. I was getting this error due to some problem in my Apex code.

Comment: @MohitKulkarni- Hi Mohit you are right. Even i checked my apex code and there was some issue in soql query. By doing hit and trail , i came to know the error in soql .So it is resolved now.  Needs to learn debugging to overcome such issue.

Comment: Upvote if you find comment/answer useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over contacts.data:

```
<template for:each={contacts.data} for:item='con'>
```

Comment: <template>
        <lightning-card title="EventWithData" icon-name="standard:logging">
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                        <template if:true={contacts.data}>
                            <p>Gopal Singh</p>
                            <template for:each={contacts} for:item='con'>
                                    <p key={con.id}>{con.Title}</p>
                                </template>
                        </template>
                    </div>
        
        </lightning-card>
    </template>